# Loading Releases for selected Jira project ID in PowerBi

Tags: powerbi, jira, powerquery, jira-rest-api

I have connected to my Jira cloud instance and loaded all my projects and their IDs into a table in Power Bi using the following query (called `LoadReleases`)  :

```
let
    apiUrl="http://my-jira-instance.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/",
    auth = "Basic " & Binary.ToText(Text.ToBinary(JiraUsername & ":" & JiraApiKey),BinaryEncoding.Base64),
    headers = [#"Content-Type"="application/json",#"Authorization"=auth],
    response = Json.Document(Web.Contents(JirApiUrl &"project", [Headers=headers])),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(response, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"key", "name"}, {"Column1.key", "Column1.name"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded Column1",{{"Column1.key", "ProjectKey"}, {"Column1.name", "ProjectName"}})

in
#"Renamed Columns"
```

This results in a table loaded into Power Bi something like this :

| ProjectKey | Project Name |
| --- | --- |
| ID-1 | My First Project |
| ID-2 | My Second Project |

I want to be able to select a project and then load all releases for that project using a different query including code something like this (which works in Excel)

```
     selectedProjectjKey = <<Get the selected project ID here somehow>>
     response = Json.Document(Web.Contents(apiUrl &"project/" & selectedProjectjKey &"/version"[Headers=headers])),
```

I thought I could use a Measure like this `SelectedProject = SELECTEDVALUE(LoadReleases[ProjectKey])` but I can't make it accessible in the second query.

Maybe I'm taking the wrong approach. Any help/suggestions much appreciated

Comment: SELECTEDVALUE is a DAX function but it appears you are trying to use it in M/Power Query. Can you clarify whether you’re looking to have all the releases for all projects in PBI and then use a slicer to filter what’s displayed or do you only want to load all the releases for a single project into PBI? I suspect it’s the former but given you’re mixing up 2 different parts with your code it’s not clear

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry for the confusion. Ideally I would like to load all the releases for a single release when it is selected and then in turn load all the PBIs (Stories, Bugs etc) when the user selects one or more releases.

Answer (score 1):

Still not entirely sure how much data you want to pull into PBI, however one way to do it is to add a new column to your `LoadReleases` table, essentially taking your *response* step from the 2nd code block and referencing the [ProjectKey] column

[image]

This will give you a column that you can expand and pull out all the relevant columns you want to use.

Comment: I guess I was hoping to load data in steps "on demand". For example the user would select "Project1" and then just get its releases (e.g "R1", "R2" and "R3". If they select R2 they would just get the backlog for that release. But maybe I have to load everything for all projects and then filter with slicers? No way to do "on demand" queries in PBI step by step?

Comment: Essentially loading it all into PBI and then using fact/dimension tables, relationships and slicers is really the model upon which PBI is predicated. There is DirectQuery, which sends queries back to the datasource for evey slice/filter/refresh etc but it's not really how PBI was originally built, and it's very datasource specific (plus there are limitations to what you can actually do). For a REST API, have a look at Chris Webb's blog for some info if you really wanted to go down that path https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2021/04/25/can-i-build-a-power-bi-directquery-dataset-on-top-of-a-rest-api/